# How do I estimate the minimum and the maximum values of normally disributed data

Tags: normal-distribution, maxima-minima

If I have a normally distributed data with mean and variance, can I get the exact value of the maximum and the minimum ? I know that 95% of the data is within 2 standard deviation of the mean but I tested it with randomly generated data and the minimum and maximum are obtained from this rule were not correct.
I followed this YouTube video
 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oCyRoA7N0Q)
It states that
minimum = mean - 2 * standard deviation
maximum = mean + 2 * standard deviation
but I tested with random sample drawn from normal distribution and it is not correct

Comment: There is no maximum or minimum.

Comment: what about the youtube video tutorial ?

Comment: As you write, we have generally 95% of data in the range M-2s, M+2s, so, 5% of data are out of this range. So M-2s and M+2s are not minimum and maximum. Minimum and Maximum are very volatile, it is impossible to give a value. And f you try to estimate a value, number of elements in the population is an important parameter.

Comment: yeah I know and suppose the population size is known. Is there a formula to estimate them ?